# Grouping data in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a dataframe column

```
df['probability'] = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
```

I need to group data like `0.5, 0.6, 0.7` and `1` as one category with output as `1` in a new column and `1.5` and `2`  as one category with output as `2` and so on. Could anyone help me in this.

Comment: coud you provide an example of the output expected?

Comment: Seems like all you want is `df['new_column'] = np.ceil(df['probability'])`

Comment: Probability greater than 1 or less than 0 is not defined. If we consider that they are not probabilities then you can use a data structure like set and group them.

Comment: Equivalent to @ernest_k's answer `df['probability-group'] = round(df['probability']+0.49)`. Thanks for the `np.ceil`, it looks smarter.